# Flutter Web Google SignIn firebase API failed with clientid not whitelisted

Tags: firebase, flutter

I always get an error with Google Api saying :
PlatformException(google_sign_in, idpiframe_initialization_failed, Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:37935 has not been whitelisted for client ID ...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help ;)